# Fuzzy Search Logic

Tags: php, contains, freetext

I am working on a search function in my PHP webpage, whereby users can enter keywords to search for. Problem is I need a fuzzy search logic that can capture keywords of different permutations and positions, therefore I am using FULL TEXT INDEX and have already installed the FULL TEXT CATALOG.

I have tried to execute the queries on SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2012, it works and the kind of results that appeared are the ones I'm looking for. However, when I add the queries in my PHP code, it doesnt work and no results appear.

Here's my query using CONTAINS :

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.entitysearch_table
WHERE CONTAINS (Name, '$entityfromform')
```

Here's my code using FREETEXT :

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.entitysearch_table
WHERE FREETEXT (Name, '$entityfromform')
```